# Question regarding Unix/Linux kernel programming

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, multicore

I would like to learn about linux/Unix kernel programming for scalable multi processors (smps). I found this book UNIX(R) Systems for Modern Architectures [http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Systems-Modern-Architectures-Multiprocessing/dp/0201633388/ref=pd_rhf_p_t_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633388) . Is there any other good resources or a better book since its released in 1994. Thank you very much in advance.

Thanks & Regards,

Mousey.

Comment: Also for any one who read the book can tell is it useful now ?

Comment: The architecture has not changed that much since 1994, and if it has changed in some area, you will learn about it, which is good.

Comment: @Anders do you know any better resource than that book ?

Comment: I have not read that book so I can't comment on that, but any random Prentice Hall UNIX book is quality. Pike, Kernighan, Thompson and Richie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely buy this excellent book! You will get thorough introduction into:

- *caches*, their types, and how to deal with them in the kernel,
- *synchronization* and what hardware primitives are behind it,
- general *kernel designs* as related to concurrency (`cli`/`sti`, giant lock, `cli`+spinlock, etc.)

The book is general enough not to be out of date by now. The only thing I don't remember mentioned there is NUMA, but I don't think there are any good published texts on this subjects yet except for maybe [Gorman's Linux memman paper](http://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/) (somebody correct me if I'm wrong here).

I think the book was really worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

[Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/salah/091/ics531/slides/Understanding%20The%20Linux%20Kernel.pdf) is a great book about how the Linux kernel is built, it describes Linux 2.2, 2.4 and 2.6 (Third Edition).

If you want to make drivers, there's [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) , and is also a reference about how Linux is built.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, [Rusty's Unreliable Guide to Kernel Locking](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/) is a must-read. After that, you can also read the file Documentation/spinlocks.txt located in the Linux kernel sources.